# virtualenvwrapper change cd behaviour and working with mkproject

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I tried to change the default behaviour of cd with virtualenvwrapper via the instructions here:  http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tips.html#changing-the-default-behavior-of-cd

and placing the code in my .virtualenvs folder and postactivate and postdeactivate files.

postactivate:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is sourced after every virtualenv is activated.

cd () {
    if (( $# == 0 ))
    then
        builtin cd $VIRTUAL_ENV
    else
        builtin cd "$@"
    fi
}

cd
```

post deactivate:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is sourced after every virtualenv is deactivated.

cd () {
    builtin cd "$@"
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work properly and now when I use `workon project` it doesn't automatically cd to the project folder listed in the .project file (which can be made with the `mkproject` command.

(Note if relevant I'm using zshell & prezto)

Answer (score 0):

The recipe you posted isn't supposed to do what you're expecting. What it actually does is that whenever you type `cd` without any path in the terminal it navigates to the virtualenv root instead of the home folder.

I'd recommend you to set up virtualenvwrapper projects so that you can separate your codebase from the virtualenv (use a requirements file instead for portability!). I.e. to add to your shell file

```
PROJECT_HOME='path/to/your/projects/folder'
```

So that `mkproject` will create a `path/to/your/projects/folder/[PROJECT_NAME]` folder for you and `workon` will automatically cd into it.

However, if you don't want to use projects, you should change your postactivate script like this in order to achieve what you want:

```
cd $VIRTUAL_ENV
```